# Call to a member function set_signature_certificate() on bool

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, digital-signature

could you help me with this problem?
I am trying to create and download a signed PDF.
Once the generated PDF file exists, I can't sign in because of this error.

"**Call to a member function set_signature_certificate() on bool**"
in browser and

"Error info at /Users/martinkravec/git/projectname/vendor/ddn/sapp/src/PDFUtilFnc.php:377: **PDF version string not found**"

in stderr.log.

I am running the following code outside CLI in Laravel 9 with PHP 8.1.9.

config/app.php

in provider:

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

In aliases:

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

Controller

```
use PDF;
use ddn\sapp\PDFDoc;

if (!defined('STDERR')) define('STDERR', fopen(__DIR__ . '/../../../storage/logs/stderr.log', 'wb'));

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php');

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf'); // temlate in resources/views/pdf.blade.php
        $fileContent = $pdf->stream();

        $obj = PDFDoc::from_string($fileContent);
        $certificatePath = __DIR__ . '/../../../storage/app/test_certificate.pfx';

        $password = '';
        $obj->set_signature_certificate($certificatePath, $password);

        $signedPdf = $obj->to_pdf_file_s();

        return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($signedPdf) {
            echo $signedPdf;
        }, 'export.pdf');
    }
}
```

When I do

```
cat ./file.pdf
```

I get file content starting with:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control:       no-cache, private
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="document.pdf"
Content-Type:        application/pdf
Date:                Sun, 28 Aug 2022 09:37:03 GMT

%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
19 0 R
]
/Count 2
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 13 0 R
>>
/XObject << 
/I1 18 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text /ImageC ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer (���d�o�m�p�d�f� �2�.�0�.�0� �+� �C�P�D�F)
/CreationDate (D:20220828113702+02'00')
/ModDate (D:20220828113702+02'00')
/Title (���D���v�k�y�.�P�D�F)
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Parent 3 0 R
/Contents 7 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 919 >>
stream
```

Comment: That error is informing you that the value of your `$obj` variable is a `bool` and **not** an `object` which is what you're treating it as.

Comment: @Peppermintology sure, but the question is "Why it is not an object?" :thinking

Comment: Because the call to `PDFDoc::from_string` method is returning false. A review of the [source code](https://github.com/dealfonso/sapp/blob/main/src/PDFDoc.php#L128) for that function suggests there is an error with the file format/structure.

Comment: Which lead us to https://github.com/dealfonso/sapp/blob/a3eec1e6cc437157bc7576ae123419b9b578c338/src/PDFUtilFnc.php#L377
with an Error message "PDF version string not found".
So the problem must be the Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class, that generates functional PDF without PDF version info probably.. but why :thinking

Comment: The code in package assumes that PDF info is on the first line of the file. 
(probably line "%PDF-1.7") so the problem is first 6 lines of file (HTTP/1.0 200 OK ...).

Comment: Removing those 6 lines manually didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

Instead of reading the PDF file content using

```
$pdf->stream()
```

we need to save the file using

```
$pdf->save($fileName);
```

which does not generate the first 6 lines of a file and probably some more things causing an error with the version.

Thanks for helping @Peppermintology anyway.